# Como puedo resolver tkinter con hilos en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola tengo un problema que no encuentro la solucion, necesito ejecutar un socket al presionar un boton pero no se que colgado la interfaz. Tengo 3 clases dependientes no se en cual tengo que llamar al tkinter.

clase que maneja los hilos del socket (server.py)

```
class Websocket(threading.Thread):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        if 'connections' not in cls.__dict__:
            cls.connections = weakref.WeakSet()
        cls.connections.add(instance)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, conn):
        super().__init__()   
        self.tokenLib = lib('C:\\Windows\\System32\\bit4xpki.dll')
        self.conn = conn
        self.state = self.CONNECTING

#la clase que inicia mi server aca estoy ejecutando mi tkinter en el init (server.py)
class WebsocketServer:
 
    def __init__(self, ws_cls):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.ws_cls = ws_cls
        raiz=Tk()
        frame = Frame(raiz,width=400,height=400)
        frame.pack()
        
        Label(frame,text="Pin del token:").grid(row=3,column=0,padx='10',pady='10')
        self.pin = Entry(frame)
        self.pin.grid(row=3,column=1,padx='10',pady='10')
        self.pin.config(show='*')
        Button(frame,text = 'ok', command = self.run).grid(row = 3, column = 3, padx='10',pady='10')
        Button(frame,text = 'cerrar', command = '').grid(row = 3, column = 4, padx='10',pady='10')
        raiz.mainloop()     
        
    def getpin(self):
        self.pinToken = self.pin.get()
        with open('./p.txt','w') as file:
            file.write(self.pinToken) 
            file.close()
                 
    def run(self, port=8887):
        self.socket.bind(('localhost', port))
        self.socket.listen()
        
        while True:
            print('Waiting connection at port %s' % (port,))
            conn, addr = self.socket.accept()
            print('Connected from %s' % (addr,))
            ws = self.ws_cls(conn)
            ws.start()
```

tengo otro archivo que ejecuto para empezar todo en otro archivo (app.py)

```
from server import Websocket, WebsocketServer


class WsEvents(Websocket):

    def onMessage(self, message):
        pass
        #print(message)
        #self.broadcast(message)

    def onConnect(self):
        print(len(self.connections))

    def onDisconnect(self):
        print('close')
    def gui(self):
        self.gui()

server = WebsocketServer(ws_cls=WsEvents)
```

Mi duda es en que momento tengo que ejecutar mi tkinter que al presionar el boton OK se inicie el server socket??
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Estás trabajando con dos bucles de enventos, el de websockets y el de tkinter. Evidentemente, si entras en uno, el otro se queda parado. No veo más solución que tener dos procesos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es separar el hilo de tkinter con otro, ya que tkinter su hilo principal siempre ira por la UI y al darle click al botón el procesador le presta total atención al nuevo hilo dejando congelada la interfaz. La biblioteca de Threading de python podría ayudarte haciendo un hilo nuevo y pasarle el proceso del botón y que el botón invoque el hilo.

Justamente ayer yo necesitaba algo parecido pero en vb y mi solución fue una herramienta que trabaja fuera de la interfaz con un ciclo adentro y delegados, pero según se Tkinter no tiene está opción, pero con un hilo que vaya fuera de la interfaz tendría que ser suficiente.

Te adjunto un link para una mejor guía.

https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/tareas-en-segundo-plano-con-tcl-tk-tkinter/

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer